# Change color of single word in Tk label widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to change the font color of a single word in a Tkinter label widget.

I understand that something similar to what I would like to be done can be achieved with a Text widget.. for example making the word "YELLOW" show in yellow:

`self.text.tag_config("tag_yel", fg=clr_yellow)`
`self.text.highligh_pattern("YELLOW", "tag_yel")`

But my text is static and all I want is to change the word "YELLOW" to show as yellow font and "RED" in red font and I cannot seem to figure out how to change text color without changing it all with `label.config(fg=clr)`.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want. A label supports only a single foreground color and a single background color. The solution is to use a text or canvas widget., or to use two separate labels.

Comment: That's a shame. I'll start looking into canvas widget then if I must. 
Thanks

Comment: @Demi2012: A canvas will probably be the most difficult of the options I mentioned.